# Android 4.4 won't allow me to save a picture when captured using adb commands

Tags: android, adb, nexus-5

My objective is to automate the process of capturing and saving a picture, with both front and back facing cameras.

I am using a Nexus 5 running Android version 4.4.2 and I have not rooted it.

I use the following commands to open the front and rear facing camera respectively:

```
>adb shell am start -a android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE --ei android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING 1


>adb shell am start -a android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE --ei android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING 0
```

(I found these commands in a previous stackoverflow post-> [ADB command to toggle camera modes in android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19600126/adb-command-to-toggle-camera-modes-in-android-device))

The problem is that while the device is in either of these modes, it will **only capture** and **not save** an image when I execute this command:

```
>adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_CAMERA
```

Once I run this command, the photo appears on the screen along with buttons to save, discard or retake the photo. However the save option does not appear to do anything.

I have two specific questions:

1.) Are there any alternative commands that I can use to open either camera?

2.) How can I make sure that the image is not being saved in some unexpected location?

I would really appreciate some help with this issue.

Edit: I don't need to store the picture on my pc, i expected it to be in /sd/card/DCIM/Camera or somewhere else on the phone.

Comment: Perhaps you should write an app to have the behavior you want, and use ADB to launch that instead?

Comment: @ChrisStratton that would make a new activity be started (even if transparent) and would possibly break the UI (e.g. close a dialog in transparent) so the picture wouldn't show right. Robotium allows you to save a picture... does it have to store to the PC?

Comment: A stock android device has no way to "store to the PC"

Comment: I would rather avoid having to write an app as I am not familiar with the API and need a quick solution.

Comment: This comment is a bit too late, but this should help.
`adb shell "am start -a android.media.action.STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA" && sleep 1 && adb shell "input keyevent 27"`

Notice the action is STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA

Answer (score 2):

I am facing the same issue in... 2020 on an "old" device that I am recycling (android **KitKat 4.4**) and this question comes first on Google.

So it looks like there are at least 2 ways to call the camera app (back on android 4.4) : `IMAGE_CAPTURE` (what you called) and `STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA`.

The first one asks for confirmation after `adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_CAMERA` has been sent and I could not find the key code to sent to validate the shooting. Consequently the photo is not saved.

The latter does not ask for confirmation and the picture is directly saved. So as a conclusion here are all the lines I input to take photos on my **KitKat** phone (replace  : `IMAGE_CAPTURE` with `STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA`).

```
adb shell "am start -a android.media.action.STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA"
adb shell "input keyevent KEYCODE_FOCUS"
adb shell "input keyevent KEYCODE_CAMERA" #actually takes photo and saves it
```

And the corresponding one-liner :

```
adb shell "am start -a android.media.action.STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA" && sleep 1 &&  adb shell "input keyevent KEYCODE_FOCUS" && sleep 1 &&  adb shell "input keyevent KEYCODE_CAMERA"
```

If it still does not work for you, keep reading :

Indeed I overlooked Pragy Agarwal's comment because first it did not work. And it did not work because the phone **screen was off**. So the power key has to be pressed first to swtich the screen on (but not press it if it was already on as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25507845/6351897)) :

```
adb shell dumpsys power | grep "mScreenOn=true" | xargs -0 test -z && adb shell "input keyevent KEYCODE_POWER"
```

And if as for me it still does not work because the camera app is somehow showing the last picture taken, you have to first press the back button when entering the camera app :

```
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_BACK
```

So all in all

```
adb shell dumpsys power | grep "mScreenOn=true" | xargs -0 test -z && adb shell "input keyevent KEYCODE_POWER" # switch the screen on

adb shell "am start -a android.media.action.STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA"

adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_BACK # go back to the "real time" camera not the gallery

adb shell "input keyevent KEYCODE_FOCUS"
adb shell "input keyevent KEYCODE_CAMERA" # shoots the picture and saves it
```

Which turns into :

```
adb shell "dumpsys power" | grep "mScreenOn=true" | xargs -0 test -z && adb shell "input keyevent KEYCODE_POWER" && sleep 1 && adb shell "am start -a android.media.action.STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA" && sleep 1 && adb shell "input keyevent KEYCODE_BACK" && sleep 1 &&   adb shell "input keyevent KEYCODE_FOCUS" && sleep 1 &&  adb shell "input keyevent KEYCODE_CAMERA"
```

What a long answer for a 7+ year old device but still doing its job somehow!